# I have a Singleton class, but returns two. Do I need two lok obj?

Tags: c#, singleton

```
public class Manager {
    private static Manager _one;
    private static Manager _two;
    private static object Obj_Lock_one = new object();
    private static object Obj_Lock_two = new object();//Do I need Obj_Lock_two here ?

    public static Manager GetOne ()
    {
            if (_one == null)
            {
                lock (Obj_Lock_one)
                {
                    if (_one == null)
                    {
                        _one = new Manager();
                    }
                }
            }

            return _one;
    }
    public static Manager GetTwo ()
    {
            if (_two == null)
            {
                lock (Obj_Lock_two) //Do I need Obj_Lock_two here ?
                {
                    if (_two == null)
                    {
                        _two = new Manager();
                    }
                }
            }

            return _two;
    }
}
```

**Do I need a second obj to lock? In GetTwo method should I use "lock(Obj_Lock_one)" or "lock(Obj_Lock_two)"**

If I only use one obj to lock, may just block one thred, I think...

SO what is the correct way?

Comment: Are you asking whether a single lock object is capable of locking only one thread? If so, are you seriously designing your system to have only one thread which uses a Manager object? If so, why don't you omit the locking right away, since you'd be writing two parallel single-threaded applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need a second obj to lock?

Using a second lock object here will *slightly* improve performance, if two thread simultaneously call `GetOne()` and `GetTwo()` for the first time at the same time. In other words: You probably won't be able to measure a difference.

> SO what is the correct way?

Don't reinvent the wheel. Scrap your code and use [Lazy initialization with `Lazy<T>`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy) instead, which is thread-safe and automatically takes care of all those thread-sync issues:

```
public sealed class Manager
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Manager> lazyOne = new Lazy<Manager>(() => new Manager());
    private static readonly Lazy<Manager> lazyTwo = new Lazy<Manager>(() => new Manager());

    public static Manager GetOne() { return lazyOne.Value; }
    public static Manager GetTwo() { return lazyTwo.Value; }
}
```